# What size is an Alchemist's Lab in PF?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, alchemy

The 200 gp and 40 lbs one ! 
How large is it ? Can I put it on a table ?

Comment: Welcome to RPG StackExchange!  Please take a look at the [About] (it's a sort of tour) when you have a moment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Presumably it would cover a large table, and possibly have some equipment with its own stands.  I don't believe images are provided in the books, but it's described as a lab or [laboratory](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/laboratory) so it seems like the sort of equipment to fill a small *room or facility*.  Something like this:

[image: Classical illustration of an alchemist laboratory]
<sub>Image from [Wikimedia commons](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Alchemical_Laboratory_-_Project_Gutenberg_eText_14218.jpg)</sub>

Compare with an [Alchemist's Lab, Portable](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/advanced/advancedGear.html#_alchemist%27s-lab,-portable) which should be, well, portable and weighs only twenty pounds, or an Alchemist's Kit which weighs only five pounds.  The mere existence of the portable version indicates the regular version is not.

Answer (score 4):

The size of an alchemist's lab is not specified by the rules. It's up to you and your GM to decide.